# What is the differences and advantages between bindParam(), bindValue() and execute(array())

Tags: php, database, pdo

```
<?php

    $db = new PDO($dsn,$username,$password);
    $uname='avi';
    $age=19;
    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO table(uname,age) VALUES(:uname,:age)');
    $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname,':age'=>$age));

    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO table(uname,age) VALUES(?,?)');
    $stmt->execute(array($uname,$age));

    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO table(uname,age) VALUES(:uname,:age)');
    $stmt->bindValue(':uname',$uname); //can be $uname or just 'avi'
    $stmt->binParam(':age',$uname); //cannot be 'avi' or value only
    $stmt->execute();

?>
```

When should we use `bindParam()`? All the previous methods seem to be easier and require less lines of code.

Whats the benefit of using `bindParam()` over other methods(`bindValue()`, `execute()`)?

Comment: why have screws when you could just use nails? It's just different ways of getting the same thing accomplished.

Comment: Yes but plenty of sites and some examples here in SO make use of bindParam when should I use bindParam? SOme exmaple in php documentation show it being used with stored Procedure that return values

Comment: different uses for different cases. in totally non-functional code, bindParam() is kind of like doing `:foo &= $var`. the foo param will be a reference to $var and simply pluck whatever value is in the variable at the time you call `execute()`. The `->exec(array(...))` version uses the variable values at that time.

Comment: If I use stored procedures can I use bindValue to store the return value in desired variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) binds the parameter by reference, so it will be evaluated at `$stmt->execute()`, which is unlike [`bindValue()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) which evaluates at the call of the function itself.

So as an example:

bindParam:

```
<?php

    try {

        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", "root", "");
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM test WHERE number = ?");
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $xy, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $xy = 123;  //See here variable is defined after it has been bind
        $stmt->execute();

        print_r($stmt->fetchAll());

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

?>
```

works great!

bindValue:

```
<?php

    try {

        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", "root", "");
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM test WHERE number = ?");
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $xy, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $xy = 123;  //See here variable is defined after it has been bind
        $stmt->execute();

        print_r($stmt->fetchAll());

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

?>
```

output:

> Notice: Undefined variable: xy

Also a few other differences:

- `bindParam()` also has the argument length which can(must) be used if you call a IN&OUT procedure to store the output back in the variable (Which also requires to append `PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT` with an OR statement to the type argument)
- With `bindParam()` & `bindValue()` you can specify the type of the value, which you can't do in the [`execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php), there everything is just a string (PDO::PARAM_STR)

Comment: hi, can you explain what it evaluates? I understand that placeholders are replaced with actual values in the sql statement.

Comment: @AAB Added an example hope it helps you to understand it more

Comment: your second example you forgot to change bindParam to bindValue

Comment: @Rizier123 how do binding with placeholders work? I thought that say my query is INSERT INTO table(age) VALUES(?) then the question mark is replaced by the value I am supplying so if it is a string then my query will be INSERT INTO table(age) VALUES('12')

Comment: @AAB *how do binding with placeholders work?* You prepare a query then you can bind the values for the placeholders and depending on what function you use you can also specify the type, the values gets replaced and the query get's executed. (This is also the reason why you can't bind things like column or table names, because your dbms must be able to prepare/build the query and if it doesn't know the column&table names it can't prepare it; But after this(preparing) you can use the query as often as you want to)

Comment: @Rizier123 if i use only execute(array($age)) is the placeholder replaced by the '12' or just 12 in the query? if its '12' the insert should fail as I am trying to insert a string in a integer field rite?

Comment: @AAB Just click on the link in my answer and there you see it in the manual that `execute()` threats all values as `PDO::PARAM_STR`, but you shouldn't get any trouble with inserting a int with `execute()`

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of bindParam over bindValue is that you can bind a variable before you decide what to put in it. Why you would actually ever need to do that, I don't know, but you might.

Bind Value

```
$x = function_call_to_determine_value();
$stmt->bindValue(':x',$x);
$stmt->execute();
```

Bind Param

```
$stmt->bindParam(':x',$x);
$x = function_call_to_determine_value();
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: So is using $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO table(uname,age) VALUES(:uname,:age)');
    $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname,':age'=>$age)); instead of bindValue ok?

Comment: @AAB Bind params via an array in execute binds them as string...with bindParam and bindValue you can specify the data type as something else if you want. So not exactly the same.

Comment: so execute(array("age"=>$age)) is different from bindParam(":age",$age,PARAM_INT) or did you mean to say I can specify age to be a string in bindParam if i wanted to?

Comment: @AAB Yes, `execute(array("age"=>$age))` will bind age as string. `bindParam(":age",$age)` will also bind it as string.  But you can do `bindParam(":age",$age,PARAM_INT)`.  You cannot bind as int with `execute(array)` at all.

Comment: how do binding with placeholders work? I thought that say my query is INSERT INTO table(age) VALUES(?) then the question mark is replaced by the value I am supplying so if it is a string then my query will be INSERT INTO table(age) VALUES('12')